# Выпадающий список из java-объектов

Tags: java, html, jsp, thymeleaf

Есть некоторый сервер, который выполняет коммуникацию с базой данных. В базе данных хранится информация о продуктах (`Product`) и производителях (`Producer`). Также есть некоторый сервер-клиент, на котором реализуется UI.
Возникла проблема с формой для добавления новых продуктов: реализовал её таким образом, что производителя можно выбрать из выпадающего списка, но этот список возвращает строку, вместо java-объекта. Как следствие, на этапе создания продукта получаю ошибку конвертации.

Есть теоретический вариант решения этой проблемы: передавать в форму также объект, который выполняет запрос на сервер(для получения данных из БД), далее каким-то образом записать id выбранного из списка производителя в отдельную переменную, и делать запрос непосредственно в UI-форме.

**Вопрос:**

1. Как это реализовать?
2. Быть может, есть более простые решения такой проблемы?

**Сущность Product:**

```
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private BigDecimal cost;
    private LocalDate shelfLife;
    private Producer producer;

    //геттеры, геттеры, конструктор
}
```

**Сущность Producer:**

```
public class Producer {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Contact> contacts;

    // геттеры, сеттеры, конструктор
}
```

На всякий случай **сущность Contact** (которая в сущности Producer):

```
public class Contact {
    private Long id;
    private Long number;

    // геттеры, сеттеры, конструктор
}
```

**Код UI-формы:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form:form action="saveProduct" modelAttribute="product">

    Title <form:input path="title"/>
    <form:errors path="title"/>
    <br><br>
    Cost <form:input path="cost"/>
    <br><br>
    Shelf life <form:input path="shelfLife"/>
    <br><br>

    Producer <form:select path="producer">   // <- часть, реализующая выпадающий список
    <form:options items="${allProducers}"/>
    </form:select>


    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">

</form:form>

</html>
```

Comment: Всё же стоит прикрепить в виде текста, продублировав и указав, что за выпадающий список отвечает такая-то часть кода. Например: *Весь код* \nЗа список отвечает эта часть:\n *код*

Comment: Что-бы вам мошли помочь добавьте участок данного кода в ввиде текста и пример данных которые доолжны находиться во втором селекте

Comment: А вы пробовали сделать из списка объект?

Comment: Добавил вами указанные изменения.

Comment: Нет, объект из списка делать не пробовал, -- не знаю как. В области html и фронтенда знаний практически нет.